# SQL Injection assistance required

Tags: security, sql-injection

I am trying to understand the below injection and what it is trying to do. What is it trying to get? The only portion I understand is the union and select part, but the full injection I am unsure of and need help understanding.

> action=&aid=1&_FILES%5Btype%5D%5Btmp_name%5D=%5C%27%20or%20mid=@%60%5C%27%60%20/*!50000union*//*!50000select*/1,2,3,(select%20CONCAT(0x7c,userid,0x7c,pwd)+from+%60%23@__admin%60%20limit+0,1),5,6,7,8,9%23@%60%5C%27%60+&_FILES%5Btype%5D%5Bname%5D=1.jpg&_FILES%5Btype%5D%5Btype%5D=application/octet-stream&_FILES%5Btype%5D%5Bsize%5D=4294

Comment: Looking at this querystring the first thing I might ask is: why is there even a select in it (blasphemy)!! Get rid of it, and only pass variables to the server, pref. by POST instead of GET. Add variables to your query with (sql)parameters.

Comment: The query isn't mine, I am seeing this in my log and was trying to understand it.  It is a get request instead of a post.

Comment: The base query is probably yours (the website you or your company is running), the perpetrator just added the union.

Comment: @MichelvanEngelen It's unlikely that they have a select in it, since it isn't selecting anything except some ints. Assuming this SQLi actually works, then they **are** doing string concatenation of user-supplied parameters into a SQL query, which is *also* blasphemy. But I would be really surprised if there was an actual `select` in the query - no one does that, haha.

Comment: It would also help to know what script file this request was directed to, and what third-party scripts (such as Content Management Systems, ecommerce, etc.) you are running. Then it would be easier to tell if this is a legit vulnerability or a blind probe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first we can url decode the string:

```
action=
&aid=1
&_FILES[type][tmp_name]=\' or mid=@`\'`/!50000union//!50000select/1,2,3,(select CONCAT(0x7c,userid,0x7c,pwd) from `#@__admin` limit 0,1),5,6,7,8,9#@`\'` 
&_FILES[type][name]=1.jpg
&_FILES[type][type]=application/octet-stream
&_FILES[type][size]=4294
```

One of these parameters sticks out as pretty suspicious.

```
[tmp_name]=\' OR mid=@`\'`
    /!50000union/
    /!50000select/1,2,3,
        (select CONCAT(0x7c,userid,0x7c,pwd) 
         from `#@__admin` 
         limit 0,1)
     ,5,6,7,8,9#@`\'`
```

In plain english, it's injecting a select query to get usernames and passwords in a format like `0x7c<user>0x7c<password>` from the `#@__admin` table (which, according to @DCoder is likely a placeholder for the actual table where these values would be kept) and appending it to your original select.

The `!50000` stuff is for bypassing your web application firewall (if you have one). If you don't, then it may just be a bot or automated attempt. Or someone following a script to see what works. The numbers aren't really useful - it may be for evading a firewall or just for debugging purposes for the attacker to see how the output looks. It's hard to tell without being able to run it.

Here's what the SQL the attacker is trying to run would look like in 'plain SQL':

```
select 
    userid,
    pwd
from 
    `#@__admin`
```

Do you have a table like this? When you go to this url for your site, does it dump the user table? If not, then you may not even have a problem and it is just an automated scan. You may still have issues with SQL injection, even if it doesn't work, but having this in your logs is not evidence of a breach... it's definitely a red flag though.

Comment: The `#@__admin` table name is probably not meant literally. A lot of frameworks use similar placeholders with table names to enable a customizable table prefix, and rewrite them internally before issuing the query.

Comment: @DCoder Oh, that's good to know. I'll update my answer to better reflect what's going on.

Comment: Thank you both, this was the answer I was looking for.  I am trying to get better at understanding what the injections means by reading it through.  This was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It's adding extra columns to the result recordset, with user/pwd information. So in essence, the user wants to collect user accounts he or she wants to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

It have to be noted that SQL injection (if any) is made possible by **another vulnerability.**

It is clear that this application is depending (or at least it is believed by the malicious user) on the some sort of homebrewed implementation of **register_globals**. A worst implementation ever.

To make this code work, the application have to take GET variables, and blindly convert them in global variables, making $_FILE array to appear not from internal process but from mere GET request.